# Windows Explorer show file modified date as ago string

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, date-modified

Is it possible to modify Windows File explorer to show file modified section as "ago" string. So it would be showing file modified "2 days 2 hours ago" or "14 seconds ago" etc..

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly configure the views that Explorer uses to display files by [changing the templates](http://www.7tutorials.com/configure-default-viewing-templates-windows-explorer-be-you-want-them) it uses. However, I'm not aware of a way to change the modified date to display an "ago" string.  There is an alternative - [MultiCommander](http://multicommander.com/).  MultiCommander is a File Explorer with many more features including the ability to specify an "ago" string for the modified date.

[image]